# Aligning and plotting tables using plot_grid()

Tags: r, plot, alignment

I have 3 tables that I'd like to be left-aligned. I swear I got this working yesterday, but all of a sudden it now returns an error (put it after the code)

Here's the data and code:

```
> dput(features)
structure(list(`2018` = c(4, 4, 4), `vs '17` = c(0, 1, 3), `vs Pilot` = c(0.47, 
0.58, 0.26), `vs ALL` = c(0.37, 0.48, 0.22), `vs General` = c(0.42, 
0.54, 0.21)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(features_matrix)
structure(c("black", "black", "black", "black", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", 
"green", "green"), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2018", 
"vs '17", "vs Pilot", "vs ALL", "vs General"
)))
> dput(youth)
structure(list(`2018` = c(4, 3, 3, NaN, NaN, NaN), `vs '17` = c(0, 
1, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN), `vs Pilot` = c(0.32, 0.63, 0.95, 
NaN, NaN, NaN), `vs ALL` = c(0.26, 0.59, 0.93, NaN, NaN, 
NaN), `vs General` = c(0.29, 0.46, 0.83, NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(youth_matrix)
structure(c("black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "green", "green", NA, NA, NA, "green", "red", "green", 
NA, NA, NA, "green", "red", "green", NA, NA, NA, "green", "red", 
"green", NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 6:5, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2018", 
"vs '17", "vs BoSTEM Pilot", "vs BoSTEM ALL", "vs General SY"
)))
> dput(engage_diff)
structure(list(`2018` = c(4, 3, 4, NaN, NaN, NaN), `vs '17` = c(3, 
1, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN), `vs Pilot` = c(1.32, -0.05, 1.21, 
NaN, NaN, NaN), `vs ALL` = c(1.22, -0.19, 1.07, NaN, NaN, 
NaN), `vs General` = c(1.21, -0.08, 1.17, NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(engage_matrix)
structure(c("black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"green", "green", "green", NA, NA, NA, "green", "red", "green", 
NA, NA, NA, "green", "red", "green", NA, NA, NA, "green", "red", 
"green", NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 6:5, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2018", 
"vs '17", "vs BoSTEM Pilot", "vs BoSTEM ALL", "vs General SY"
)))

comp_table_cols <- c("2018", "vs '17", "vs Pilot", "vs ALL", "vs SY")

tt <- ttheme_minimal(core=list(fg_params = list(col = features_matrix)),
                     colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="black", fontface=1L, cex = 0.8)),
                     rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col=NA))
                     )
features_diff_plot <- tableGrob(features_diff, theme = tt)

colnames(youth_diff) <- comp_table_cols
youth_matrix <- ifelse(engage_diff < 0, "red", ifelse(youth_diff > 0, "green", "black"))
youth_matrix[,1] <- "black"
tt <- ttheme_minimal(core=list(fg_params = list(col = youth_matrix)),
                     colhead=list(fg_params=list(col=NA)),
                     rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col=NA))
                     )
youth_diff_plot <- tableGrob(youth_diff, theme = tt)

colnames(engage_diff) <- comp_table_cols
engage_matrix <- ifelse(engage_diff < 0, "red", ifelse(engage_diff > 0, "green", "black"))
engage_matrix[,1] <- "black"
tt <- ttheme_minimal(core=list(fg_params = list(col = engage_matrix)),
                     colhead=list(fg_params=list(col=NA)),
                     rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col=NA))
                     )
engage_diff_plot <- tableGrob(engage_diff, theme = tt)

colnames(stem_diff) <- comp_table_cols
stem_matrix <- ifelse(stem_diff < 0, "red", ifelse(stem_diff > 0, "green", "black"))
stem_matrix[,1] <- "black"
tt <- ttheme_minimal(core=list(fg_params = list(col = stem_matrix)),
                     colhead=list(fg_params=list(col=NA)),
                     rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col=NA))
                     )
stem_diff_plot <- tableGrob(stem_diff, theme = tt)

plot_grid(features, youth, engage,
          , ncol = 1
          , rel_heights = c(3, 6, 8)
          #, axis = "l"
          , align = "h"
          )
```

Error:

```
Warning message:
In align_plots(plotlist = plots, align = align, axis = axis) :
  Graphs cannot be horizontally aligned, unless axis parameter set. Placing graphs unaligned.
```

Wish I could upload a picture of what the output should look like, but it should be so that all the columns just align up with each other.

I tried messing around with the `axis` and `align` parameters of the plot_grid function, but can't get it to plot these tables with the left-alignment. I don't get the error message when I uncomment the `axis` parameter, but it doesn't resolve the alignment issue. Any help would be appreciated